# How to do this REST API call in Python?

Tags: python, rest, api, python-requests

I'm struggling with how to properly do this REST API call in Python using `requests` package.

```
curl --user aa43ae0a-a7a7-4016-ae96-e253bb126aa8:166291ff148b2878375a8e54aebb1549 \
  --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{ "startDate": "2016-05-15" , "endDate": "2016-05-16", "format": "tsv", "dataset": "appStart" }' \
  https://analytics.cloud.unity3d.com/api/v2/projects/aa43ae0a-a7a7-4016-ae96-e253bb126aa8/rawdataexports
```

I don't know, how to set the parameters of:

```
r = requests.post("https://analytics.cloud.unity3d.com/api/v2/projects/aa43ae0a-a7a7-4016-ae96-e253bb126aa8/rawdataexports", ...)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job :

```
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('aa43ae0a-a7a7-4016-ae96-e253bb126aa8', '1662[....]549')
payload = {
    "startDate": "2016-05-15" ,
    "endDate": "2016-05-16",
    "format": "tsv",
    "dataset": "appStart",
}
url = "https://analytics.cloud.unity3d.com/api/v2/projects/aa43ae0a-a7a7-4016-ae96-e253bb126aa8/rawdataexports"
result = requests.post(url, json=payload, auth=auth)
```

1. Authentication : `--user` argument of curl comand allows to setup an [HTTP Basic Auth](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)
2. `--data` was a JSON payload, while the requested content-type is configured (via headers) with `Content-Type: application/json`. Simplify this with `requests` [using `json` argument and passing a valid python dict as payload](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests). The payload will be converted to json, and the correct header will be added to the request to retrieve a response with json data.

**Be careful !** In your question, you provided the user/password used to call this REST API. If this information is the real one, posting it on Stack Overflow is probably a security issue !

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. The user/password is not mine, it's from the example provided by Unity.